# Extra white space between images?

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, removing-whitespace

So I've got a row of images on a site I'm building and there is some un-coded white-space b/w the images.

The margin is set to zero and the debugger doesn't show any padding or border on them either. I have no idea why that white-space is there.

Here's the HTML

```
<figure class="carousel-inner">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="images/team/alex_morrales.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="images/team/david_kim.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="images/team/jenny_tabers.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="images/team/joey_barrett.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="images/team/melinda_lee.jpg" alt="">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="images/team/rachel_dotson.jpg" alt="">
</figure>
```

And CSS

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sliding-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

And related CSS reset code

```
body, html, div, blockquote, img, label, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, ul, ol,
li, dl, dt, dd, form, a, fieldset, input, th, td
{
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  border: 0; 
  outline: none;
}
```

I'm in Google Chrome by the way.

Here's a screenshot of it

[image]

Any help in understanding this conundrum is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how inline/inline-block elements are presented. There are a few ways to get rid of those spaces.

1. Place all the `img` tags in one line (do not hit the return key). This is kind of messy to read though:

```css
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
</figure>
```

2. Another is to set the `font-size` of the parent to `0`:

```css
figure {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
</figure>
```

Remember to reset the `font-size` of the children if you have text there.

3. You can also use `float` like so:

```css
figure {
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure img {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
</figure>
```

4. Add `HTML comments` with the opening right next to the end of the tag and its closing at the next line:

```css
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- not
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- really
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- a
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- fan
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- of
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- this
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- inline
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- element
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""><!-- fix
  --><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
</figure>
```

5. Put the closing tag at the next line:

```css
figure img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""
  ><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">      
</figure>
```

Those are the fixes/hacks I know. Not really sure if there are any other ways. :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I actually found an article on css tricks that explains all these methods also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The image has a default 4px `margin-right`

Apply this to your css code to fix it.

**CSS**

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sliding-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block; //added
    margin-right: -4px; //added
}
```

Other way is using `float:left` to the `.sliding-image`

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
}

.sliding-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This `margin-right: -4px;` is just a vulgar hack, sorry. Try to set `font-size:48px` on the `<figure>` or its parent.

Comment: Yeah, I know about setting a negative margin but I'm looking for a legit way to fix this.

Comment: i just updated my answer. i think that would do the output you want

Comment: Alright, thanks rckjncwlng, but setting the font size to 0 as SGS Venkatesh suggested worked. 

But is that solution just another hack?

Comment: Nvm, it's a legit fix to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set `font-size: 0` in your `.carousel-inner` style.

```
.carousel-inner {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Comment: Alright, this worked, but why?

Comment: The extra space is because of the spaces/tabs between the elements. When you set `font-size: 0`, the spaces between these elements is taken care of. [Check this](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) article for more information.

Comment: I actually found that article after asking this, but thanks for taking the time to answer. Cheers!

Comment: Good that you found the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the default white space between `inline-block` elements, try to add comment tag between each img (`inline-block` element).

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

.carousel-inner {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
}

.sliding-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<figure class="carousel-inner">
  <img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
--><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
--><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
--><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
--><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
--><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</figure>
```

Comment: Good to know, I didn't know that the img element had a default style of "inline-block". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you can try this code, with no breakline between  `<img>` tag

```
<figure class="carousel-inner"><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></figure>
```

And same as this, with html comment tag

```
<figure class="carousel-inner">
   <img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
   --><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
   --><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
   --><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
   --><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"><!--
   --><img class="sliding-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</figure>
```